# Database First EF6 add data to table with Custom ViewModel

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I using MVC 5.1 and EF 6.1 database first model. I don't like the view that was created by the scaffolding as it uses all the database columns. On the create view I just want the user to input the required fields all other data can be added through editing the details view. I have created the a view model to use other than the .edmx generated one. The view works as expected but when the create action button is click the post operation dies with a "[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

```
Here is my view model

     public class DesktopCreateViewModel 
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string SERIAL_NUMBER { get; set; }

    public int Model_DesktopId { get; set; }
    public int DeviceType_DesktopId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string MAC1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Arrival Date")]
    public DateTime ARRIVAL_DATE { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    [Display(Name = "Record Updated")]
    public DateTime RECORD_UPDATED { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int Location_CodeId { get; set; }
    public int MemoryId { get; set; }
    public int MonitorId { get; set; }
    public int PlantId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public int Operating_SystemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeparmentId")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeviceType_DesktopId")]
    public virtual DeviceType_Desktop DeviceType_Desktop { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Location_CodeId")]
    public virtual Location_Code Location_Code { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MemoryId")]
    public virtual Memory Memory { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Model_DesktopId")]
    public virtual Model_Desktop Model_Desktop { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MonitorId")]
    public virtual Monitor Monitor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Operating_SystemId")]
    public virtual Operating_System Operating_System { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PlantId")]
    public virtual Plant Plant { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<DesktopCreateViewModel> Create_Desktop { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DesktopCreateViewModel> Desktops { get; set; }


Here is the portion of the controller that fails
     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ICollection<DesktopCreateViewModel> desktop)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in desktop)
            {
                db.Entry(desktop).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

         ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "DEPARTMENT1", desktop.DepartmentId);
         ViewBag.DeviceType_DesktopId = new SelectList(db.DeviceType_Desktop, "Id", "DEVICE_TYPE", desktop.DeviceType_DesktopId);
         ViewBag.Location_CodeId = new SelectList(db.Location_Code, "Id", "LOCATION_CODE1", desktop.Location_CodeId);
         ViewBag.LocationId = new SelectList(db.Locations, "Id", "LOCATION1", desktop.LocationId);
         ViewBag.MemoryId = new SelectList(db.Memories, "Id", "MEMORY1", desktop.MemoryId);
         ViewBag.Model_DesktopId = new SelectList(db.Model_Desktop, "Id", "MODEL", desktop.Model_DesktopId);
         ViewBag.MonitorId = new SelectList(db.Monitors, "Id", "MONITOR1", desktop.MonitorId);
         ViewBag.Operating_SystemId = new SelectList(db.Operating_System, "Id", "OS", desktop.Operating_SystemId);
         ViewBag.PlantId = new SelectList(db.Plants, "Id", "PLANT1", desktop.PlantId); 
        return View(desktop);
    }
```

This is the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Desktop</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SERIAL_NUMBER, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SERIAL_NUMBER)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SERIAL_NUMBER)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model_DesktopId, "Model", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("Model_DesktopId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model_DesktopId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceType_DesktopId, "Device Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("DeviceType_DesktopId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceType_DesktopId)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MAC1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MAC1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MAC1)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ARRIVAL_DATE, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ARRIVAL_DATE)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ARRIVAL_DATE)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RECORD_UPDATED, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RECORD_UPDATED)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RECORD_UPDATED)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationId, "Location", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("LocationId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location_CodeId, "Location Code", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("Location_CodeId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location_CodeId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemoryId, "Memory", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("MemoryId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemoryId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MonitorId, "Monitor", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("MonitorId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MonitorId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlantId, "Plant", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("PlantId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlantId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "Department", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Operating_SystemId, "Operating System", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("Operating_SystemId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Operating_SystemId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Is `desktop` null?

Comment: Yes it is null. It's not getting the data from the view.

Comment: Can you post the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action is expecting a collection of viewmodels (`ICollection<DesktopCreateViewModel>`), but the view only contains one. Try changing to:

```
public ActionResult Create(DesktopCreateViewModel desktop)
```

Comment: That's a whole different problem. You're trying to save a `DesktopsCreateViewModel` but it's not an entity in your data context. Entity Framework can only work with entities it knows about. Typically with a view model you would map it to an entity and save that. You can perform the mapping manually or using something like AutoMapper.

Comment: Ok made the changes and change the foreach loop to db.Desktops.Add(desktop);. This is not valid so not sure now how to get the data added the database.

Comment: You need to convert `desktop` (which is a `DesktopCreateViewModel`) to a `Desktop` (which is an entity in your data context) and pass that to `.Add()` or `.Entry()`.

Comment: Thanks just need to figure out how to get it done then. AutoMapper sounds best but not real clear on how to use it so gues more research on my end

Comment: Just try to do this manually to make sure it will work before introducing AutoMapper. `var desktopEntity = new Desktop { desktop.SERIAL_NUMBER, desktop.ARRIVAL_DATE, ... }; db.Desktops.add(desktopEntity);`

Comment: Now I'm getting Error 3 Cannot initialize type 'Inventory.Models.Desktop' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' c:\users\t0217mw\source\workspaces\inventory db\inventory\inventory\controllers\desktopcontroller.cs 61 49 Inventory
 getting more confused but I am catching on.

Comment: Sorry I should've double-checked the code. Should be like this... `var desktopEntity = new Desktop { SERIAL_NUMBER = desktop.SERIAL_NUMBER, ARRIVAL_DATE = desktop.ARRIVAL_DATE, ... };`